# apache with node.js

Tags: apache, node.js, express, pug

I am having some problem in writing jade script.So  am wondering if i could host my webpages 
on apache. Once the page opens it will open a socket to port 3000 and then  node server will start pushing notifications.

Will it give some warning in browser? any other concern with this approach?

So Apache willl run on 80
node on 3000

Answer (score 0):

I had done this once for testing purposes, works well, no warnings were given.

Concerns would be that splitting website background on two servers will bring an extra complexity to the project. If you will load any parts from node initially, it will cause longer loading time, because you will only be able to establish connection to node when main page from apache will finish load. Also there is a possibility of duplicated code doing same thing under different servers.

In conclusion I would say that if there is no special needs from other servers, I would try my best to keep everything on node with jade, even if that would require some learning, it will definitely payback later.

If the only reason you're using apache is to serve the initial page, I would suggest the [nginx](http://nginx.com/) in that case, because it is more lightweight but I haven't tested it by myself.